# Restrict PowerShell file upload in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Issue: Restrict PowerShell file upload in C#

Description: I am working on one of the task to restrict PowerShell file in File upload in c#. I tried multiple ways/solution i.e. File Signatures, Winista.MimeDetect etc nuget packages but the problem is it is unable to detect powershell power.
Issue is I want to restrict powershell upload (not based on extension), someone can change the pdf file to powershell and upload, then we have to restrict this, this should not be allowed.

I tried above different nuget packages in .NET, when I try to upload it will give me null value, So I thought to check null value for identifying powershell file but the problem if you upload text file also, it will give me NULL value.

Also, I tried with urlmon.dll

Please help, this is very important.

Comment: Except by trying to identify the syntax, you won't be able to get far, a powershell file is only a text file after all. You could try a parsing approach to check if the fil is valid powershell https://fuqua.io/blog/2017/12/parsing-powershell-programatically/ but it opens up a bunch of other issues.

Comment: I tried difficult ways in .NET to identify if the file is power shell file or not but no luck for me.  It would be great if you something handy that can help me to resolve this issue. It's very urgent